# VBA logical operator values in expressions

Tags: vba, logic, expression

In VBA I am trying to combine logical and numeric expressions, for example, using a counter to determine color of a chart series:

`RGB(255 * (ctr2 = 0), 255 * (ctr2 = 1), 255 * (ctr2 = 2))`

However I notice that the true condition evaluates as -1, and false as zero.  Being used to C I had expected a logical true to evaluate as 1.  Is this correct?  Is there a better way of achieving this in a single line (rather than a series of if statements or switch etc).

Example:

```
Sub testLogical()
x = 3
y = (x = 1) * 255
Debug.Print y   ' displays "0"
y = (x = 3) * 255 ' displays "-255"
Debug.Print y
End Sub
```

Comment: You could have a wrapper function to return 1 when true.

Comment: `255 * -(ctr2 = 0)` etc